# Where is the calculator executable in elementary OS 6 Odin?

Tags: calculator

When the calculator is launched, it indicates that the command for the program is `io.elementary.calculator`. When one opens the terminal and runs `io.elementary.calculator` it gives

`io.elementary.calculator: command not found`

What would be the path of the calculator executable to be able to run it from a terminal and also attach a key shortcut to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculator app is packaged as flatpak, you can run it from terminal with `flatpak run io.elementary.calculator`. Run `flatpak list` to see the other default flatpak apps which you can run with corresponding command like the calculator.

You can also use the same command like in the terminal to make a keyboard shortcut.